# Deleting all indexes except selected UICollectionView Index

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to delete all the indexes of my data source except the one that is selected. Heres the code I am using.

```
 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            NSMutableIndexSet *indexesToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
            NSUInteger currentIndex = 0;
            for (NSIndexPath *cellIndexes in collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
            {
                if (cellIndexes.row != indexPath.row)
                {
                    [indexesToDelete addIndex:currentIndex];
                }
                currentIndex++;
            }
            [self.searchUsers removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToDelete];
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }];
    }
```

My collection view is inside my tableView so I have that reload the data upon reloading the tableView.

The error I get with my indexDelete logic is that my '`indexesToDelete`' `NSMutableIndexSet` is always nil. and of course I can't send a nil object to `removeObjectsAtIndexes`

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my logic. Any ideas?

EDIT: I didnt seem to change anything, but not I am not getting crashes, but It is deleting the wrong indexes.

Comment: Does your tableview is displaying values taken from NSObject or Just Strings at every row?

Answer (score 0):

IndexPaths for table and collection views have two parts for the section and row, they are not integers. Instead of using the integer, currentIndex, just add cellIndexes to an array (rather than a mutableIndexSet),

```
NSMutableArray *indexesToDelete = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSIndexPath *cellIndexes in collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems){
    if (cellIndexes.row != indexPath.row) {
        [indexesToDelete addObject:cellIndexes]; // it would be better to call this variable cellIndex since it's a single index
    }      
 }
```

Comment: Just realized this, however it needs to be an indexset in order to perform the method removeObjectsAtIndexes. no?

Answer (score 0):

I was deleting at the indexes of the enumeration. Simply needed to grab the indexes of the nonselected cells instead. oops

```
   NSMutableIndexSet *indexesToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
        for (NSIndexPath *cellIndexes in collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
        {
            if (cellIndexes.row != indexPath.row)
            {
                [indexesToDelete addIndex:cellIndexes.row];
            }
        }

        [self.searchUsers removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToDelete];
        NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```